# Why am I getting NAs for predictions? Population-level predicted means using glmmTMB for a zero-inflated gamma model

Tags: r, prediction, glmmtmb

First I set up my zero-inflated gamma model:

```
fit <- glmmTMB(y ~ x1 + x2 + x3 + x4 + x5 + x6 + ... + x29, 
               data = data1, 
               ziformula = ~1, # a single zero inflation parameter applying to all observations
               family = Gamma(link = "log"))
```

The I get a summary:

```
summary(fit)

Family: Gamma  ( log )
Formula:  y ~ x1 + x2 + x3 + x4 + x5 + x6 + ... + x29
Zero inflation: ~1
Data: data1
     AIC      BIC   logLik deviance df.resid 
 94097.1  94409.8 -47009.6  94019.1    22351 


Dispersion estimate for Gamma family (sigma^2): 10.7 

Conditional model:
                          Estimate Std. Error z value             Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)               6.892188   0.204138   33.76 < 0.0000000000000002 ***
x1                       -0.385346   0.050716   -7.60     0.00000000000003 ***
x2                       -0.009425   0.002612   -3.61             0.000307 ***
x3                       -0.138414   0.049467   -2.80             0.005140 ** 
x4                       -0.177845   0.094630   -1.88             0.060193 .  
x5                       -0.014657   0.115329   -0.13             0.898868    
...
x29                       0.087996   0.103055    0.85             0.393173    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Zero-inflation model:
            Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)
(Intercept)   -22.15     431.79  -0.051    0.959
```

Then predict means at a population level for different levels of x1:

```
newdata <- data.frame(x1=unique(data1$x1), 
       x2=NA, x3=NA, x4=NA, x5=NA, ... x29=NA)

predict(fit,
        type = "response", 
        newdata = newdata )

[1] NA NA
```

I know there is overdispersion and I should pick a different model, but that shouldn't prevent me from getting estimates, right?

Comment: The issue is your prediction is ```x1* (some values) + x2* NA+x3*NA+...=NA``` because ```5+NA=NA```. You might want to check out ```emmeans``` package.